# spring oauth2 without xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to understand how to use oauth2 spring and spring boot to create a provider and a client without using XML. I have a provider that exposes a service but how can I access it from client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loads of samples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation. With tests. And one sample that is just a client app (all you need is an `OAuth2RestTemplate` and an `@EnableOAuth2Client`).